# enable HTML5 mode in meanjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I've included `$locationProvider.html5Mode()` in my config file and it works.  However when I refresh the page, it redirects back to my express app rather than my angularjs front end.

How do I make sure anything other than `/api` gets routed to my index.html page?

```
angular.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName).config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
    ])
```

Comment: this change would need to happen in your node.js routing, so we'll need to see that. have you even added middleware that would do this redirect?

Comment: Yup as Kevin B said you need to have some redirect rules so any missed requests under this directory or requests that aren't for files get redirected to index.html so the paths that miss a file on the server go to the index.html so angular can handle the route from there.  This depends on the specifics of how you're actually running node.

Comment: Nope I haven't added any middleware.  Can you show an example?

Comment: @JustinYoung Did you find the answer ?

Comment: Nope.  The newer version has it enabled by default though. If you're not already too deep in I'd recommend upgrading.  The structure of modules is vastly improved as well.

Answer (score 0):

In old version(0.3.0) adding following code after Globbing routing fixed my issue.
I added this to line number 130 in /config/express.js.

```
app.get('/*', core.index);
```

Hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

In core.server.routes.js replace

`app.route('/').get(core.index);`

by

`app.route('/*').get(core.index);`